# Share extension pass selected text to textview

Tags: swift, share-extension

I am creating an iOS Share Extension but am running into a problem. The function `shareSetup` checks if the attachment is of type text. As you can see in the code below value of `selectedText` gets assigned but then clears.
Note: `selectedText` is going to be set as the textview value.

```
    var selectedText = ""

    func shareSetup() {
        let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem
        let contentTypeText = kUTTypeText as String
    
        for attachment in extensionItem.attachments! {
           if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeText){
               attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypeText, options: nil,completionHandler: { (results, error) in
                   let text = results as! String
    
                    self.selectedText = text
                    print(self.selectedText) //prints correct value text
                   _ = self.isContentValid()
               })
           }
        }
        print(self.selectedText)// prints nothing
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        shareSetup()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

*attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier:* method seems to be asynchronous - so it's body (completionHandler) executed not directly on the call but some time later, when item will be loaded. In this case *print(self.selectedText)* print already existed text. But second print executed synchronously and at this exact point of time this value still empty - loadItem not executed yet.

So when you execute this code - you got it work it steps similar to this:

- start shareSetup
- start to execute for loop
- start attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier calls
- finish the loop
- print(self.selectedText) where is nothing
- got calls completionHandler when items was loaded and execute its body
- print(self.selectedText) where it already has something

Look more for async calls, and usage of completion handlers.

Comment: A lot of tutorials ([link](https://medium.com/@ales.musto/making-a-share-extension-that-accepts-text-and-urls-in-combination-with-coredata-swift-3-a0139c0f9800)) I referred to use this same method and it seems to work there.

Comment: Is there and alternate way of accessing the selected text when presenting a share extension?

Comment: in link you provided text accessed inside attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: .it's the right method to do this and it works perfectly. Why you need any alternate way for this? (you don't have any)

Comment: Like I said in the original question, I can't assign a value to ``` selectedText``` . So what I meant to ask was, how do I assign the selected text to the share extension textView.

Comment: You can do it only inside attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier handler, use it - assign to text view, save somehow - I don't understand the problem. You don't have other options.